# Mediawiki Edit toolbar missing after upgrade from 1.23 to 1.27

Tags: php, jquery, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'm having this problem. When I want to edit something, the toolbar does not show up. I upgrade the wiki from 1.23 to 1.27 and the php version from 5.3 to 5.6.

I opened the console in google chrome and I am getting this errors:

> - Gadget "wikEd" was not loaded. Please migrate it to use ResourceLoader.
> - Uncaught ReferenceError: importScript is not defined. -> (anonymous function) @
>     load.php?debug=true&lang=es&modules=site&only=scripts&skin=monobook&version=9f6eab9f43c7:26
> - Uncaught ReferenceError: importScriptURI is not defined. ->
>
> initializeRefTools @
>   load.php?debug=true&lang=es&modules=ext.gadget.refToolbar&only=scripts&skin=monobook&version=9f6eab…:16
>
> fire @
>   load.php?debug=true&lang=es&modules=jquery%2Cmediawiki&only=scripts&skin=monobook&version=kvvF0DI1:3148
>
> fireWith @
>   load.php?debug=true&lang=es&modules=jquery%2Cmediawiki&only=scripts&skin=monobook&version=kvvF0DI1:3260
>
> ready @
>   load.php?debug=true&lang=es&modules=jquery%2Cmediawiki&only=scripts&skin=monobook&version=kvvF0DI1:3472
>
> completed @
>   load.php?debug=true&lang=es&modules=jquery%2Cmediawiki&only=scripts&skin=monobook&version=kvvF0DI1:3503

[Here is an image of the errors](https://gyazo.com/9e19607dbec6b21ff29e4e7889dc7474)

I went to special:accessories and I edited the configuration of wikEd and I put this: `wikEd[ResourceLoader]|wikEd.js`

but still not working.

Also I configured WikiEditor Extension:

```
wfLoadExtension( 'WikiEditor' ); // at the bottom of my LocalSettings.php

$wgDefaultUserOptions['usebetatoolbar'] = 1;

$wgDefaultUserOptions['usebetatoolbar-cgd'] = 1;

$wgDefaultUserOptions['wikieditor-preview'] = 1;

$wgDefaultUserOptions['wikieditor-publish'] = 1;
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You have a JavaScript error which breaks everything depending on JavaScript. Try and edit your Common.js/Monobook.js to remove any reference to `importScript` and `importScriptURI`, empty the wikEd gadget etc. until you remove the offending code.

Then you can restore the functionality you actually need by following the [migration guide](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Migration_guide_(users)) and importing recent versions of the gadgets.